# Stop .htaccess redirect with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My site uses an .htacess file to redirect the root domain name to another URL. The current redirect looks like this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://example2.com/ [R=301,L]`

I only want the root domain to be redirected (example1.com to example2.com) so the above works correctly. However if a query string is used within the old URL. For example

http://example1.com/?pages=3

The redirect still works which I don't want. Im just having the redirect problem when a query string is used, anything else is fine:

http://example1.com/ - Does Redirect  ✓

http://example1.com/home - Doesn't redirect ✓

http://example1.com/?page=3 - Does Redirect X - need this not to redirect

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a ? at the end of the destination to discard old querystring :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://example2.com/? [R=301,L]
```

If you dont want to redirect when the request contains query string, you may use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Drat, you posted `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` first. I came up with the exact same condition.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I used the second option and works perfectly!