# Changing css dependent on domain and adding "?" into domain

Tags: javascript, html, css, dns

First post here but I'll get on with it, I was having some trouble with finding out how to change a site's CSS dependent on the domain, what I mean by that is like if I wanted "example.com" to display a coming soon page *but* if you change the domain to "example.com?bypass=keyhere" then it displays the actual site that is being built, I mentioned CSS because I was thinking of changing visibility of elements, etc. but I do not even know how to get started with having it detect what the proper domain is.

Comment: Use ``.htaccess`` to restrict any *query* from **URL**.  Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249423/stop-htaccess-redirect-with-query-string

Comment: You can use JavaScript to detect the key in the URL, and then add a CSS class to the HTML, and just nest all of your styles within that class.

Comment: you can do this using js :
refer this for ex : https://jennamolby.com/how-to-display-dynamic-content-on-a-page-using-url-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query params using

```
function urlParam(name){
   var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
   if (results == null){
      return null;
  }
  else {
     return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
  }
}

if (urlParam.bypass === 'keyhere') {
     // if you want to do something
} else {
     document.body.classList.add('hideContent')
}
```